# what does this command mean in bash

Tags: bash, sh

I have come across a bash script which contains the commands:

```
cd .git/hooks
[ `eval ls -l | grep -io 'Post-Commit' | wc -l` -eq 1 ] && echo 'post-commit file check... Pass' || echo 'post-commit file check... Fail'
```

I believe it is to check for a file named `post-commit` in the `.git/hooks` folder. But even if I create the file `post-commit` inside the directory I get the output as: `post-commit file check... Fail`.

Am I doing something wrong here?
I create my file using:

`cat > post-commit`

and then I write into it and make it into an executable using `chmod +x post-commit`

Any help will be really appreciated

Comment: The one-liner command above works just fine, make sure you are in the correct path. However you can drastically slim down the check, there's no need to spawn 4 external commands  `[` + `ls` + `grep` + `wc` to get your job done. Yes, `[` is an external command. The following check is a pure-bash example using only internal shell commands (note the double square brackets `[[ ]]`), with the same final result: `[[ -f 'post-commit' ]] && echo 'post-commit file check... Pass' || echo 'post-commit file check... Fail'`

Comment: Try to execute `ls -l | grep -io 'Post-Commit'`  in hooks directory. How many you see in output? Should be one.

Comment: http://explainshell.com/ is your friend. "Please explain this code" questions are generally off-topic here.

Comment: @Losko, ...note, though, that `foo && bar || baz` is something of an antipattern -- it's possible for _both_ `bar` and `baz` to run, plus `bar` is treated as a "checked" command so `set -e` won't trigger an exit if it fails (and ERR traps won't trigger either). Much better to use `if foo; then bar; else baz; fi` to avoid any ambiguity.

Comment: (What's the purpose of the `eval`? It's best to avoid using it unless you have a really unavoidable need for it, but I don't see it doing anything useful at all in this particular case).

Comment: Thank you so much, all of your discussions here have helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this script seems to be *aimed at* Git hooks, it has no dependency on Git in any way, so I dropped the [git](/questions/tagged/git) and [githooks](/questions/tagged/githooks) tags.  It also has nothing to do with Linux so I dropped the [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) tag.

The `eval` here is entirely unnecessary.<sup>1</sup>  We can drop it:

```sh
[ `ls -l | grep -io 'Post-Commit' | wc -l` -eq 1 ] &&
  echo 'post-commit file check... Pass' ||
  echo 'post-commit file check... Fail'
```

(I broke this into more lines for readability).

As [Losko notes in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67235715/what-does-this-command-mean-in-bash#comment118845173_67235715), `[` is *nominally* an external command.  In practice it's actually built into most shells, including bash, so that there's no fork-and-exec.

The backquoted section, however, does require a fork-and-exec.  Text of the form `` `command` `` is more or less equivalent to code of the form `$(command)`.  The `$(...)` form is generally superior because it provides sane nesting, so if there's a choice of which to use, one should usually prefer the `$(...)` form.  In any case, it just means: *run the command shown and insert its output here*.  So we're going to run:

```
ls -l | grep -io 'Post-Commit' | wc -l
```

as [metallic notes in another comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67235715/what-does-this-command-mean-in-bash#comment118848325_67235715).

The `ls -l` does the obvious: a long listing.

The `grep -io` has two flags: `-i`, meaning *ignore case*, and `-o`, meaning *show only the matched part as output*.  So this is going to look for `ls -l` output in which the line contains `POST-COMMIT`, `post-commit`, `pOSt-COMmit`, and so on.

The `wc -l` does the obvious: count lines.

The end result is that we count the *number of files* that have this string *in* their file name.  A file named `this-GETS-RUN-post-COMMIThaste-er` for instance gets counted.

The final result of this count gets compared for numeric equality to `1`.  If the number *is* one, the `&&` part of the clause is run; if not, the `||` part is run.

Overall, this script fails to do anything useful, because it's too sloppy.  It allows mixed-case file names; Git does not.  (However, on file systems where the *OS* allows case-insensitive matching of file names, Git's use of strictly lowercase results in accessing mixed-case or uppercase names after all.)  If we find two or more files that match, it complains, yet files whose names simply have a *sub*-match are probably not an issue here.

---

<sup>1</sup>An `eval` in a shell command makes the shell do various expansions first, *then* run the command.  Where it's useful—e.g., `eval $cmd`—it's also generally pretty dangerous: you must exercise extremely strict control over what goes in `$cmd`.  Where there are no expansions, as in this case, it's useless.  Avoid it as much as possible.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was really helpful. As a beginner in bash scripting I don't know much about how the syntax works, but your answer helps out a lot and I also appreciate you for going into so much detail to explain each part of it!